# How can I track down the origin of Devel::Peek

Tags: perl, perl-module

Out-of-the-blue I started to see lines like this:

```
SV = PVIV(0x38fe3f0) at 0x3de5b80
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY)
  IV = 0
  PV = 0
```

These do not appear *consistently* and if I run the script repeatedly, with the *same* input, this output sometimes appear, sometimes even *twice* and sometimes not at all.

And every once in a while, the script hangs and displays an error message saying "Perl unfortunately stopped running."

It is obviously the output of `Devel::Peek`, but none of *my* modules uses it and the only CPAN modules I use are Log::Log4perl, 
Data::Dumper::AutoEncode (which of course uses Data::Dumper) and List::Util. 
All these I use extensively and I never got this kind of output.

Box: Win-7 Pro 64 bit

Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 18 subversion 2) configuration:

```
  Platform:
    osname=MSWin32, osvers=6.2, archname=MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
    uname='Win32 strawberry-perl 5.18.2.1 #1 Tue Jan  7 22:32:35 2014 x64'
```

Can someone suggest steps I could do to find the origin of this and why it happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

At the top of your script, add the following:

```
BEGIN {
    use Carp qw( );
    use Devel::Peek qw( );
    my $old = \&Devel::Peek::Dump;
    my $new = sub { Carp::cluck("Devel::Peek::Dump got called somewhere!"); &$old };
    no warnings 'redefine';
    *Devel::Peek::Dump = $new;
}
```

This needs to happen before anyone imports `Dump` from Devel::Peek.

The output of `Carp::cluck` will include a stack trace.

Comment: In deed it doesn't :(

Comment: Updated the code in this answer to fix the problem I had previously mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can't find the source of the message because you're looking for the wrong thing. It could also be the output of `sv_dump` from an XS module.

```
use Inline C => <<'__EOI__';

   void dump_sv(SV* sv) {
      sv_dump(sv);
   }

__EOI__

dump_sv(1);
```

Output:

```
SV = IV(0x34cd588) at 0x34cd598
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (IOK,READONLY,PROTECT,pIOK)
  IV = 1
```

Options to locate these calls:

- Run `perl` under a debugger, and set a breakpoint in `sv_dump`. (Most reliable)
- Dump the symbols of your `.dll` files, and grep them for `sv_dump`. (Maybe?)
- Grep the source distributions of the modules you have installed. (Least reliable)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you folks.

The culprit was most probably the lack of `$sth->finish;` statement after a couple of DB retrieval operations. Since I added those, I don't see these messages anymore!